# How to select terms which contain certain letters?

Tags: pattern-matching, filtering, conditional

I would like to select the term `Subscript[Cos\[CapitalDelta], Subscript[p, B]]` of expression

```
     Times[Complex[0,32],
        Dot[Cross[OverVector[n],Subscript[OverVector[Δ],1]],
    Subscript[OverVector[Δ],A]],Dot[Subscript[OverVector[Δ],1],Derivative[1]
[Subscript[OverVector[Δ],A]]],
Subscript[CosΔ,
    Subscript[p,B]],
    Subscript[SinΔ,Subscript[p,A]],Derivative[1][Subscript[CosΔ,Subscript[p,B]]],Derivative[1]
    [Subscript[SinΔ,Subscript[p,A]]]]
```

I can use Take[exp,{-3}] but it is not general. The selection rule should indeed be the terms that start with `C`. For example, in the above expression, I want terms `Subscript[CosΔ, Subscript[p, B]]` and `Derivative[1][Subscript[CosΔ, Subscript[p, B]]]`.

For other times I may have expression like

```
    Times[Complex[0,32],m,Ε2,
Dot[Cross[OverVector[n],Subscript[OverHat[OverVector[p]],A]],
Subscript[OverVector[Δ],A]],Subscript[C,Subscript[p,B]],
Subscript[S,Subscript[p,A]],
Subscript[SinΔ,
Subscript[p,A]],Derivative[1][
Subscript[CosΔ,Subscript[p,B]]]]
```

For this expression, I really need the term

```
 Subscript[C, Subscript[p, B]]
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: In your expressions it is not clear, how their terms are connected to one another. Now they are simply written as several different input lines within the same cell. Do they form a list? Or, may be, they should be connected by the sign plus? Or what? Further, what do you mean by such a notation as `Subscript[Cos\[CapitalDelta], Subscript[p, B]]`? Do you mean, may be, `Cos[Subscript[\[CapitalDelta], Subscript[p,B]]]`?

Comment: @ Alexei Boulbitch sorry, I have changed the messy code. Now, it is more clear.

Comment: It still seems to contain a syntax error: `Subscript[Cos\[CapitalDelta], Subscript[p, B]]` does not exist within the Mma syntax, unless you mean that it is such a variable with so a strange name. Further, now your expression represents a single term: a product of several factors. In this case I do not understand the sense of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case, this may work out:

```
FullForm /@ Cases[
  exp,
  x : Subscript[a_, b_] /; StringTake[ToString[a], {1, 1}] == "C",
  All
  ]
```

> {Subscript[CosΔ, Subscript[p, B]],
>   Subscript[CosΔ, Subscript[p, B]]}

It does miss the derivative around the second occurrence, though. I don't know whether this iss desired or not.

Comment: @ Henrik Schumacher  How to take into account the Derivative?

Comment: Cases[exp, 
 x : (Derivative[1][Subscript[a_, b_]]) | Subscript[a_, b_] /; 
  StringTake[ToString[a], {1, 1}] == "C", All]